# Dynamically update title property based on current menu item using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, semantic-ui, menuitem, title

```js
var a; titleText=""; hardCodedTitle="";
var menuCount = document.getElementsByClassName().length;
$('a.UserSelectedItems').each(function(){
for(a=0; a<menuCount; a++){
title += $('a.UserSelectedItems')[a].innerText;
if(title == "B-1"){
hardCodedTitle = "B-1: Business sector 1";
$('a.UserSelectedItems').attr('title',hardCodedTitle);
}
else if(title == "B-2"){
hardCodedTitle = "B-2: Business sector 2";
$('a.UserSelectedItems').attr('title',hardCodedTitle);
}
else if(title == "D-5"){
hardCodedTitle = "D-5: Development group 5";
$('a.UserSelectedItems').attr('title',hardCodedTitle);
}
else{
hardCodedTitle = "Not categorized";
$('UserSelectedItems').attr('title',hardCodedTitle);
}
}
});
```

```html
<div class="ui menu" id="Menu">
    <a class="UserSelectedItems" title="A-1">A-1</a>
    <a class="UserSelectedItems" title="A-2">A-2</a>
    <a class="UserSelectedItems" title="B-1">B-1</a>
    <a class="UserSelectedItems" title="B-2">B-2</a>
    <a class="UserSelectedItems" title="D-2">D-2</a>
    <a class="UserSelectedItems" title="D-5">D-5</a>
    <a class="UserSelectedItems" title="E-2">E-2</a>
    </div>
<input type="text" id="populateTitle" placeholder="hardcoded title populate OnClick menu items">
//OnClick of menu item, hardcode title value as per the js should be populated in this text box
```

I have a requirement where on hovering the each menu item(menu is dynamically updated as per user selection), hard coded title has to be populated dynamically. I'm able to get the dynamic menu item as title as of now, and I need help to populate hard-coded title based on each dynamic menu item  using javascript.

Above is example code(not the exact code that works) to show my scenario. Firstly based on user selection, menu items are populated(few might be unselected). So my requirement is to display hardcoded value as title based on menu items selected by user.

If user selects items: B-1,B-2,D-5 , then hardcoded title has to be shown as pop-up on hovering each menu item.

```
div class="ui menu" id="Menu">
...
<a class="UserSelectedItems" title="${eachDataSet.getKey()}">${eachDataSet.getKey()}</a>
</div>
```

My actual html code looks somewhat as above. Thanks!

2nd edit...
I used the below  code(answered by @rucha) and it's working fine. Now additional requirement is I have an input field of type text. How can I populate title(hard-coded title for each menu item) on click of each item, as text box value?

Comment: Pls. share your code so people know how to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some basic errors like,

1. While accessing the `document.getElementsByClassName()`, you need to pass the class name. Like `document.getElementsByClassName("UserSelectedItems");`
2. If you're using $.each, you need not use `for` loop again for the same purpose.

I have modified the code so that inside the $.each block, the title is being assigned to the each `<a>` link, based on your conditions.

```js
var a;
titleText = "";
hardCodedtitle = "";
var menuCount = document.getElementsByClassName("UserSelectedItems");
$(menuCount).each(function(index, item) {
  title = item.title;
  if (title == "B-1") {
    hardCodedTitle = "B-1: Business sector 1";
    $(item).attr("title", hardCodedTitle);
    $(item).attr("data-hardcoded", "true");
  } else if (title == "B-2") {
    hardCodedTitle = "B-2: Business sector 2";
    $(item).attr("title", hardCodedTitle);
    $(item).attr("data-hardcoded", "true");
  } else if (title == "D-5") {
    hardCodedTitle = "D-5: Development group 5";
    $(item).attr("title", hardCodedTitle);
    $(item).attr("data-hardcoded", "true");
  } else {
    hardCodedTitle = "Not categorized";
    $(item).attr("title", hardCodedTitle);
    $(item).attr("data-hardcoded", "true");
  }

});

function populateTitle(e) {
  if (e.currentTarget.hasAttribute("data-hardcoded")) {
    $("#populateTilte").val(e.currentTarget.getAttribute("title"));
  } else {
    $("#populateTilte").val("");

  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui mini vertical menu" id="verticalMenu">
  <a class="UserSelectedItems" title="A-1" onclick="populateTitle(event)">A-1</a>
  <a class="UserSelectedItems" title="A-2" onclick="populateTitle(event)">A-2</a>
  <a class="UserSelectedItems" title="B-1" onclick="populateTitle(event)">B-1</a>
  <a class="UserSelectedItems" title="B-2" onclick="populateTitle(event)">B-2</a>
  <a class="UserSelectedItems" title="D-2" onclick="populateTitle(event)">D-2</a>
  <a class="UserSelectedItems" title="D-5" onclick="populateTitle(event)">D-5</a>
  <a class="UserSelectedItems" title="E-2" onclick="populateTitle(event)">E-2</a>
</div>

<input type="text" id="populateTilte" placeholder="Hardcoded Title">
```

Comment: I have made the changes as above and it's working fine for me. Thank you!!

Comment: Can we populate those hard-coded values in constant field? I mean onclick of each menu item, the hard-coded title of clicked item will be populated in the field created

Comment: So, I have input text box-  <input type="text" id="populateTitle" placeholder="on click/ on selection of each menu item it's hard-coded title is populated ">. I want to populate this text box with title on each selection. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Edited the code. Created a new data-attribute on each element and the same value is populated on text box.

Comment: OnClick is working fine, I tried using onload function for the same. By default the 1st menu item is being selected and I want to keep it as it is.. can do the same onload? I tried <a class="UserSelectedItems" title="A-1" onload="populateTitle (event)" OnClick="populateTitle (event)">$(each dataset.getKey()}</a>.. but it's not working for me..

Comment: There is no onload event for anchor tag. You need to add it to the document onload function.

Comment: I did pass the function as- document.load = function(){...} and it's not working... Can we use any other way? So as per the above code text field is empty initially.. instead can I populate the title for only first menu item by default?

Comment: I added jQuery function to get 1st element populated onload, and it's working fine. $(document).ready(function (){$("#populateTilte").val($('a.UserSelectedItems')[0]. title);});